# convert a list of multiple tuples to a distinct dictionary by date/int date

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I got a data and came out as a list of tuples:

```
   m = [('bob', 'base-certificate', 12, 3), ('vov', 'base-certificate', 11, 3), ('foo', 'base-certificate', 13, 3), 
     ('doo', 'base-certificate', 14, 3), ('foo', 'case-certificate', 3, 3), ('joo', 'base-certificate', 1, 3), 
     ('bob', 'case-certificate', 1, 3), ('dad', 'base-certificate', 9, 3), ('star', 'case-certificate', 2, 3), 
     ('coo', 'case-certificate', 1, 3), ('goo', 'case-certificate', 3, 3), ('sun', 'case-certificate', 2, 3),
     ('woo', 'base-certificate', 6, 3), ('sun', 'base-certificate', 12, 3), ('goo', 'base-certificate', 4, 3), 
     ('star', 'base-certificate', 11, 3), ('coo', 'base-certificate', 14, 3), ('vov', 'case-certificate', 1, 3),
     ('woo', 'case-certificate', 2, 3), ('foo', 'standard-certificate', 1, 3), ('doo', 'standard-certificate', 1, 3),
     ('vov', 'standard-certificate', 1, 3), ('doo', 'case-certificate', 1, 3), (None, 'base-certificate', 5206, 3), 
     (None, 'standard-certificate', 479, 3), (None, 'case-certificate', 140, 3), (None, 'base-certificate', 432, 4), 
     (None, 'case-certificate', 43, 4), (None, 'standard-certificate', 44, 4)]
```

I have tried default(dict) to try and convert it  to a format i would like which is like this: the last integer in the tuple was assigned to key 'x' variable that was created in the loop in the code i tried below. where x represents the last integer(the date) and base-cert which is the cert_type represents the integer before the last int above.

```
#{x: 3, bob: { base-cert: 12, case: 1, standard: 0}, foo:{ base-cert: 12, case: 1, standard: 0 }, woo: {base-cert: 12, case: 1, standard: 0}, doo:{base-cert: 12, case: 1, standard: 0}}
 #{x: 4, bob: { base-cert: 12, case: 1, standard: 0}, foo:{ base-cert: 12, case: 1, standard: 0 }, woo: {base-cert: 12, case: 1, standard: 0}, doo:{base-cert: 12, case: 1, standard: 0}}
```

the code i tried was:

```
 msm_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for msm, cert_type, count, date in m:
    if 'x' not in msm_dict[date]:
        #assigns date to variable x
        msm_dict[date]['x'] = date
    # create a dictionary 
    r={ cert_type: count}

    #assign the dict to the msm
    msm_dict[date][msm]= r
msm_list = list(msm_dict.values())      
print(msm_list)
```

The result was:

```
[{'x': 3, 'bob': {'case-certificate': 1}, 'vov': {'standard-certificate': 1}, 'foo': {'standard-certificate': 1}, 'doo': {'case-certificate': 1}, 'joo': {'base-certificate': 1}, 'dad': {'base-certificate': 9}, 'star': {'base-certificate': 11}, 'coo': {'base-certificate': 14}, 'goo': {'base-certificate': 4}, 'sun': {'base-certificate': 12}, 'woo': {'case-certificate': 2}, None: {'case-certificate': 140}}, {'x': 4, None: {'standard-certificate': 44}}]
```

my thought process was:

1. assign the date to a variable x in a loop while selecting the defaultdict variable: 'x': date
2. select the msm as a key and assign a value which is a dictionary that contains the cert_type and their respective count
   each date as different values for cert_type based on the msm type.

what can i do in this case? am thinking of it wrongly. I am definitely missing something

Comment: Please clarify your expected output. I don't follow the logic at all. What is `x` representing? You say a "date" but 3 is not a date...

Comment: x is a variable that is equal to the integer in the tuple, so i can get the output x: 3, in order words i assigned the date int to x

Comment: But there are two integers in each tuple... Which one are you picking? And why aren't foo and joo and dad and star included in your expected output where `x=3`?

Comment: the second to the last integer is to be assigned to the cert_type, so x= 3, base-certificate = count which is the second to the last value

Comment: I also don't see any 4 in any tuple where bob is included. Your output makes no sense. Your logic isn't explained sufficiently. It's also difficult to understand *why* you'd even want your data structured this way.

Comment: so first integer represents the count and the other the date, i tried to assign the date to x and the count integer to the cert_type. so the for every date there is a msm code related to each cert_type and count

Comment: What should happen for `None` names?

Comment: the data structure just makes it easier to get a graph

Comment: Please provide a complete representation of your expected output given the input data you've provided. It's not clear where `{'x': 4, 'bob'....}` comes from.

Comment: the none values should be assign zero

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand your desired output, from your question.
This is how I suggest, and let me know if it is not what you intended:

```
from itertools import groupby

certkeys = {
  'base-certificate': 'base-cert', 
  'case-certificate': 'case', 
  'standard-certificate': 'standard'
}
d = []
for day, byx in groupby(m, lambda a: a[3]):
  x = {'x': day}
  d.append(x)
  for (name, ckey, cval), g in groupby(byx, lambda a: (a[0], a[1], a[2])):
    if name not in x:
      x[name] = {c: 0 for c in certkeys.values()}
    x[name][certkeys[ckey]] = cval

print(d)
```

And the result for the `m` you provided is:

```
[{'x': 3,
  'bob': {'base-cert': 12, 'case': 1, 'standard': 0},
  'vov': {'base-cert': 11, 'case': 1, 'standard': 1},
  'foo': {'base-cert': 13, 'case': 3, 'standard': 1},
  'doo': {'base-cert': 14, 'case': 1, 'standard': 1},
  'joo': {'base-cert': 1, 'case': 0, 'standard': 0},
  'dad': {'base-cert': 9, 'case': 0, 'standard': 0},
  'star': {'base-cert': 11, 'case': 2, 'standard': 0},
  'coo': {'base-cert': 14, 'case': 1, 'standard': 0},
  'goo': {'base-cert': 4, 'case': 3, 'standard': 0},
  'sun': {'base-cert': 12, 'case': 2, 'standard': 0},
  'woo': {'base-cert': 6, 'case': 2, 'standard': 0},
  None: {'base-cert': 5206, 'case': 140, 'standard': 479}},
 {'x': 4, None: {'base-cert': 432, 'case': 43, 'standard': 44}}]
```

Comment: Yes this is the desired output, thank you very much....I also worry about convert this to JSON because of the None, I tried it but I got an error...